# How to Upload File With HTTP URL Connection Java From Java Swing

Tags: java, httpurlconnection

So I want to move a file to another folder by calling an API, with only one button in java swing. So when started a start button the file that is in a specific folder will move and uploaded automatically in the server, when I press the stop button then the process will stop. This is upload process by calling an API, but I got a response code 500, can anyone help me? The token is automatically generated, so there's no problem with the authorization, the only problem was I couldn't upload the files.[I already test in on the postman and got the response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5YCVg.png)

```
 String docPath = "file.pdf";   
    String url = "https://xxx.co/uploads?=";
    String USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0";

    URL obj = new URL(url);
    HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection)obj.openConnection();

    con.setRequestMethod("POST");

    //add request header
    con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
    con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");
    con.setRequestProperty("content-type", "application/json");
    con.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");            
    con.setRequestProperty("Authorization",token);
    // Send post request
    con.setDoInput(true);
    con.setDoOutput(true);
    int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
    byte[] buffer;
    int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;

    String[] q = docPath.split("/");
    int idx = q.length - 1;
    File file = new File(docPath);
    FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
    InputStream is = null;
    DataOutputStream outputStream = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
    bytesAvailable = inputStream.available();
        bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
        buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

        bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
        while (bytesRead > 0) {
            outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            bytesAvailable = inputStream.available();
            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
        }
    int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
    String responseMsg = con.getResponseMessage();

    System.out.println("\nSending 'POST' request to URL : " + url);
    System.out.println("Post parameters : " + docPath);
    System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);
    System.out.println("Response Msg : " + responseMsg);

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(inputLine);
    }
    in.close();

    return response.toString();
```

Comment: Is there any additional information on the 500 return? Have you test the API through Postman?

Comment: yes, i already test the API through the postman and it works, the additional information the error message Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL: https:/xxx.co.id/upload/?=
 at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1900)
 at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1498)
 at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:480)
 at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode

Comment: You will have to look at the server log. Response code 500 is deliberately intended to leak no information about the error.